# Parse JSON in ROR and call 2 controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am getting JSON in below format from my application

```
{"list":[{"orderno":"02201308231133","itemno":"w01","name":"t01","amount":"120","status":"done"},{"orderno":"02201308231133","itemno":"w02","name":"t02","amount":"120","status":"done"},{"orderno":"02201308231133","itemno":"w03","name":"t03,"amount":"120","status":"done""}]}
```

Now I need to do 2 tasks from above JSON: first add the above rows in lists table as it is, second:extract first 2 digits from orderno i.e.02 in above case and update another table (or call another controller) with status(done) for value extracted (02).

I am able to do first task. The controller code for same is:

```
def create
    lists = params[:list].collect{|list_attributes| List.new(list_attributes)}
    valid,not_valid = lists.partition{|list| list.valid?}

    if not_valid.blank?
      lists.map(&:save)
      @lists = lists
      format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @list, status: :created, location: @list }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

The above method inserts rows in DB table.
Now I am unable to figure out how to parse JSON to extract value before calling create method in lists controller. Once I have values I need to call both tables to update. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install the gem `'json'` which has easy-to-use methods to parse JSON data (its documentation is at https://github.com/flori/json).

Then you can read your json with:

```
JSON.parse(string)
```

which will give you an array of string and hashes. You can get your order number's first two digits by iterating through such array, getting the value corresponding to the `:order` key, then take the first 2 digits and convert them into an integer using:

```
order_no[0,2].to_i
```

Comment: This library is actually faster than json gem and has comatibility api with it: https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby

Comment: Thanks for the input. My another issue is how to go to different controller with the value extracted.

Comment: Do you have a model associated with that list? If so, once you have saved the data into the db, you can just access from every controller you want. If not, why not?